# Python documentation input variable type hints

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-typing

### TLDR

I'm noticing a significant difference in the information presented by the official python docs compared to what I'm seeing in the PyCharm hover-over / quickdocs. I'm hoping someone can point me to where I can find the source of this quickdoc information such that I can use it outside of PyCharm as a general reference.

For example in the python docs for [os.makedir](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.makedirs) I see:

```
os.makedirs(name, mode=0o777, exist_ok=False)

    Recursive directory creation function. Like mkdir(), but makes all intermediate-level directories needed to contain the leaf directory.

    The mode parameter is passed to mkdir() for creating the leaf directory; see the mkdir() description for how it is interpreted. To set the file permission bits of any newly created parent directories you can set the umask before invoking makedirs(). The file permission bits of existing parent directories are not changed.

    If exist_ok is False (the default), an FileExistsError is raised if the target directory already exists.

    Note

    makedirs() will become confused if the path elements to create include pardir (eg. “..” on UNIX systems).

    This function handles UNC paths correctly.

    Raises an auditing event os.mkdir with arguments path, mode, dir_fd.

    New in version 3.2: The exist_ok parameter.

    Changed in version 3.4.1: Before Python 3.4.1, if exist_ok was True and the directory existed, makedirs() would still raise an error if mode did not match the mode of the existing directory. Since this behavior was impossible to implement safely, it was removed in Python 3.4.1. See bpo-21082.

    Changed in version 3.6: Accepts a path-like object.

    Changed in version 3.7: The mode argument no longer affects the file permission bits of newly created intermediate-level directories.
```

But in the quickdocs I see:

```
os def makedirs(name: str | bytes | PathLike[str] | PathLike[bytes],
             mode: int = ...,
             exist_ok: bool = ...) -> None
makedirs(name [, mode=0o777][, exist_ok=False])  Super-mkdir; create a leaf directory and all intermediate ones.  Works like mkdir, except that any intermediate path segment (not just the rightmost) will be created if it does not exist. If the target directory already exists, raise an OSError if exist_ok is False. Otherwise no exception is raised.  This is recursive.
```

Where is this quickdoc type hinting information coming from and where can I find a complete reference with all these type hints such that I can reference it outside of PyCharm?

### Background

Coming mainly from a strongly typed language like Java, I struggle to make constructive use of the python documentation with regards to function input parameter types. I am hoping someone can elucidate a standard process for resolving ambiguity compared to my current trail+[lots of]errors approach.

For example, the [os.makedir](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.makedirs) function's first parameter is `name`.

```py
os.makedirs(name, mode=0o777, exist_ok=False)
```

It is not apparent to me what sorts of things I can pass as `name` here. Could it be:

- A [str](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/File.html#mkdirs())? If so, how should I create this? Via a string literal, double quoted string? Does this accept `/` separators or `\` separators or system dependent?
- A [pathlib.Path](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/File.html#mkdirs())?
- Anything [pathlike](https://docs.python.org/3/glossary.html#term-path-like-object)?

[Note the above are rhetorical questions and not the focus of this post]. These are all informed guesses, but if I were completely new to python and was trying to use this documentation to make some directories, I see two options:

1. Read the source code via some IDE or other indexing
2. Guess until I get it right

The first is fine for easier to understand functions like `makedirs` but for more complicated functions this would require gaining expertise in a library that I don't necessarily want to reuse and just want to try out. I simply don't have enough time to become an expert in everything I encounter. This seems quite inefficient.

The second also seems to be quite inefficient, with the added demerit of not knowing how to write robust code to check for inappropriate inputs.

Now I don't want to bash the python docs, as they are **LEAPS and BOUNDS** better than a fair few other languages I've used, but is this dilemma just a case of unfinished/poor documentation, or is there a standard way of knowing/understanding what input parameters like `name` in this case should be that I haven't outlined above?

To be fair, this may not be the optimal example, as if you look towards the end of the doc for `makedirs` you can see it does state:

> Changed in version 3.6: Accepts a path-like object.

but this is not specifically referring to `name`. Yes, in this example it may seem rather obvious it is referring to `name`, but with the advent of type-hinting, why are the docs not type hinted like the quickdocs from PyCharm? Is this something planned for the future, or is it too large a can of worms to try to hint all possibilities in a flexible language like python?

Just as a comparison, take a look at Java's [java.io.file.mkdirs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/File.html#mkdirs()) where the various constructors definitely tell you all the options for specifying the path of the file:

```java
File(File parent, String child)
// Creates a new File instance from a parent abstract pathname and a child pathname string.
File(String pathname)
// Creates a new File instance by converting the given pathname string into an abstract pathname.
File(String parent, String child)
// Creates a new File instance from a parent pathname string and a child pathname string.
File(URI uri)
// Creates a new File instance by converting the given file: URI into an abstract pathname.
```

Just reading this I already know exactly how to make a File object and create directories without running/testing anything. With the quickdoc in PyCharm I can do the same, so where is this type hint information in the official docs?

Comment: I believe PyCharm uses Typeshed https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/type-hinting-in-product.html#typeshed https://github.com/python/typeshed

Comment: In general, yes, Python is duck typed, and the documentation also often "duck types" the definitions, leaving it somewhat ambiguous what the exact types are supposed to be. Usually it's mentioned in the text, or the initial paragraphs of the module documentation clarify what types are typically used throughout the module. But sometimes it's indeed a bit unclear, and you're kind of expected to go by typical convention or pick it up by context.

Comment: I was unaware of typeshed as a whole. Good to know! From a brief look, it looks like it is to be used by other tools like PyCharm, mypy, etc, but I'm not seeing anything compiled to a general reference like the online docs. Is this not a thing? I feel like the info in typeshed should somehow be merged/integrated with the docs. It feels off that there is documentation about type hints not in the docs. :/

Comment: Pycharm probably uses a) typeshed (pointed above) for **type hints** and b) internal docstrings for long text. Try `help(os.makedirs)` in your terminal to see the same output as Pycharm gives. It is created in `.py` files of python itself, like [this](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/main/Lib/os.py#L200) - `os.makedirs` is documented in code. Python documentation is **not** built from docstrings for numerous reasons.